# Laravel: Helper or API call?

Tags: laravel

My app (Laravel/Vue) has some API endpoints like `/api/price/{id}` and `/api/buy/{id}` first endpoint gives the price of a product and second buy x quantity (passed by POST) of that product.

Prices have too much volatility (think things like cryptocurrencies), so the `/price/` endpoint will do some calcs and give the realtime price. When I click the buy button on the browser it goes to the `/buy/` endpoint, of course. The first thing it has to do is to calculate the real time price, just as the `/price/` endpoint does, then write to the database etc.

For some reason beyond my control the endpoints are in different controllers, I have a `PriceController` and a `BuyController`, so I have several options to make this work:

1. I write the same code in both endpoints. Of course, I don't like a bit this solution, because of maintenance
2. (Which I'm currently using) Inside my `BuyController` I do an API call to `PriceController`, and yeah, sure it works, but I find it quite strange to go to the network to access something local, I don't know if it will have any performance impact under load (in development, it doesn't seem to be any)
3. Should I do a helper function to do all the calcs needed and use it as the price source for both `/price/` and `/buy/` endpoints? I feel this approach might be better. I normally don't use helpers so I can't start imagining what name to give to the helper function.

What should be the "correct" approach?

Maybe the correct way is to "unify" `/price/` and `/buy/` endpoints and have a function inside the resulting controller, but I don't know how many changes should I make to the rest of the app.

Comment: Names are hard but other than that approach (3) is I think the best one for your particular use case. (1) is of course bad, but (2) is actually not unreasonable if you at any point plan to switch to using microservices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should write a Service and use it in both controllers (if you move your controller's logic to service even better - ), but if you are using 'calculation logic' frequently, then maybe using a helper function would be more suitable.

if you are not comfortable using services, you can also use [this approach](https://medium.com/@remi_collin/keeping-your-laravel-applications-dry-with-single-action-classes-6a950ec54d1d)

Comment: I don't quite understand how the service aproach may work, I'll do some research about it, thanks!

Comment: Loved the article! thanks a lot, that's a pretty smart way to use `singletons` (as the old name was), Yeah, I think that may work for me